# Change DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD depending on whether I'm on server or not

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing at my local computer. Therefore I exchange files between the localhost and server.

In wp-config I'd like to check if I'm on the server or not.
Depending on the result I'd change DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD.

Right now I do it manually.

**wp-config.php**

```
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
// define( 'DB_USER', 'gr_academ' );

define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
// define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'secret' );
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Can you *not* upload the config file?

Comment: Let me rephrase, when you upload your files... can you avoid overwriting your configuration file? Your upload tool probably has a way to ignore certain files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem.

Is local site on port 80?

`if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80) { define( 'DB_USER', 'root' ); }`

Are sites using different versions of PHP?

`if (PHP_VERSION_ID == 70424) { define( 'DB_USER', 'root' ); }`

Or detect by host.

`if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'something.local') { define( 'DB_USER', 'root' ); }`

Or check server directory

`if (strstr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/Volumes/')) {  define( 'DB_USER', 'root' ); }`

Note: PHP Version is best, if you use WP-CLI.